# Converting an array of arrays into an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I currently have data that is coming back in the following format:

```
[
[144, 'test@email.com', '7358'],
[145, 'test2@email.com, '7358'],
[146, 'test3@email.com, '7359'],

.....


]
```

I am trying to convert the array of arrays into an array of objects that would look like the following:

```
[
{employeeId: 144, WorkEmail: 'test@email.com',  ClubNumber: '7358'},
{employeeId: 145, WorkEmail: 'test2@email.com', ClubNumber: '7358'},
{employeeId: 146, WorkEmail: 'test3@email.com', ClubNumber: '7359'},
]
```

I am having trouble wrapping my mind around assigning keys to the individual items in each array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let array = [
[144, 'test@email.com', '7357'],
[145, 'test2@email.com', '7358'],
[146, 'test3@email.com', '7359'],
];

let result = array.map(([employeeId, WorkEmail, ClubNumber]) => ({employeeId, WorkEmail, ClubNumber}))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why not simply `array.map(([employeeId, WorkEmail, ClubNumber]) => ({employeeId, WorkEmail, ClubNumber}))`?

Comment: You are right that's shorter.